# rails で、ファイルの中身を omission 付き truncate する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rails では、 `String#truncate` が利用でき、たとえば以下のような挙動を示します。

```
'hogehoge'.truncate(6, omission: '...')
# => 'hog...'
```

File の中身を、同様に omission 付きで表示しながら truncate したいと思いました。

File が大きかった場合を考えて、 File の中身をすべて読み込むのは避けたいと思っています。

#### 質問

- rails で、 File に対して omission 付き truncate のようなことをやる場合にはどうしたらよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

`IO.read(N)` や `IO#read(N)` で指定**バイト数**だけ読むことが出来ますが、今回は文字単位でなければならないので単純には使えませんね。

基本的には `truncate` する長さより多めに読み込んで `String` のインスタンスが作れれば、あとは `String#truncate` に任せられるのではないでしょうか。具体的には

```
io.each_char.first(1500 + 1).join.truncate(1500, omission: '(以下略)')
```

のようになります。